# EWS(Exchange WebService) API not working in Open JDK 11 as well in Zulu Java 11

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, java-11, openjdk-11, azul-zulu

I have been using *EWS(Exchange Web Service)* for reading emails from a shared email box in *Java 8*.

After upgrading to *Java 11 (Open JDK 11/Zulu Java 11)*, facing exceptions while reading emails.

This is the Exception:

> **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/http/HTTPException** at
> Microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalFindFolders(ExchangeService.java:370)
> ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:na]

Comment: what exceptions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is the Exception:: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/http/HTTPException
                at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalFindFolders(ExchangeService.java:370) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:na]
                at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.findFolders(ExchangeService.java:425) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:na] 
    
caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException

Answer (score 6):

Adding the below dependency in your pom.xml will help in reading emails from a shared mailbox.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```